# Best Practice to index file content in hibernate Search

Tags: java, spring, lucene, cxf, hibernate-search

I am using CXF and Spring and Hibernate Search.

I have one Main class which have several attributes and its one attribute is of type Attachment(File). i will store all attributes in database except Attachment(File) which i will store on File System.

So now my query is that:

if user gives some string of Attachment(file content) then i should return the object of Main Class whose Attachment(File) contains these given string.

So how i should use indexing of file content to achieve my requirement.

Kindly suggest me the way to do this in an optimized way.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to extract from files like pdf, doc, etc with [Apache Tika](https://tika.apache.org/)  you can achieve this. Any way just write field bridge for your file.

```
public class FileContentBridge implements StringBridge {

   public String objectToString(Object object) {

     //extract file content 
      return "extracted";
   }
}
```

Apply bridge

```
@FieldBridge(impl = FileContentBridge.class)
private File attachment;
```